# How to play CoD WaW Custom Zombies with Friends?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

I bought this game thinking I would be able to play some custom zombies with my cousin but whenever we try to join each others game, it would say that the game session is no longer available.  Any Fix?